# timer0_millis always returns 0

Tags: arduino-uno, pwm, millis

I am trying to make a simple debounce function as explained [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/debounce) but the condition `if((millis()-timeCheck)>reboundDelay)` is never met.

As you can see in my code below, I am trying to control a PWM with two push buttons. I am currently sending it on a LED.

With AS7 and vMicro I put some breakpoints and realized that `timeCheck` was stuck at 0 and was an `unsigned int` instead of the `unsigned long` I declared. With the debugger I looked inside of the `millis()` function and saw that `timer0_millis` wasn't increasing neither, stuck at 0.

Here is my short code (it's a sketch, it can surely be rewritten in a more efficient way) :

```
int PWM=9;
int dutyP=2;
int dutyM=3;
int duty=123;
bool stateP=0;
bool stateM=0;
bool prevStateP=0;
bool prevStateM=0;
unsigned long reboundDelay=500;
unsigned long timeCheck=millis();

void setup() {
  pinMode(PWM,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dutyP,INPUT);
  pinMode(dutyM,INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  stateP=digitalRead(dutyP);
  stateM=digitalRead(dutyM);
  if(stateP != prevStateP || stateM != prevStateM) {
    timeCheck=millis();
  }
  if((millis() -  timeCheck) > reboundDelay) {
    if(stateP==1) {
      duty=duty+25;
    } else if(stateM==1) {
      duty=duty-25;
    }
    analogWrite(PWM,duty);
    prevStateP=stateP;
    prevStateM=stateM;
  }
}
```

And finally, the strange part. When I upload it on my Genuino Uno for like 30 seconds, the pushbuttons do nothing (it may be that the `if` works) and afterwards I can increase and decrease the duty cycle but without the delay that the condition should bring (the LED flashes really fast due to an overflow in analogWrite).

Any help is welcomed, the strange part is secondary to me but I would really like to make `millis()` work properly.

Comment: bool variables have two possible values true and false.  1 and 0 are technically ints, you might be OK but I wouldn't do it.  You should also check for wrap on duty.

Comment: Would it be possible to just do this loop?  `loop(){Serial.println(millis());delay(500);}` If you are right about millis not moving then this will prove it.  There _may_ be something in the debuggers that interfere with millis.

Comment: I tried to but nothing happen in the serial monitor despite : 
Port closed
Uploading to I/O board
Opening port
Port open

Comment: Should I write stateP==true or false instead of 1 or 0 ?

Comment: Did you try with an empty project?  If so you have a bigger problem :(

Comment: true == 1 false == 0, yes

Comment: Trying in a new project right away.

Comment: Do this on an Arduino Uno / Atmel ATmega328P.   There are many different kinds of Arduino boards with many processors.  They all do not work perfectly with respect to their boot loader software and SDK implemtations.  Also, I would not define the type and call a method to assign a value to the type outside of a method.  I would define "timeCheck" then assign it a value within the methods.

Comment: Sorry for the wait AS7 crashed... I made a new projet just inserted your lines in the loop function and started debugger on the .ino file... and it worked. Didn't I had to add the .cpp file before I could debug ? Anyway, there is still no sign of millis in the serial monitor.

Comment: @st2000 I didn't understood what you meant in the first part of your comment, should I configure something in a certain way ? I am using an genuino uno rev3 with an ATMega328P.
For the second part, the unsigned long timeCheck=millis(); it was a wild try, I forgot to clean it up before posting here. Thank you.

Comment: I tried in multiple ways, Serial.println() doesn't work at all. I might as well install AS6.2 and see if it works better.

Comment: There are many types of Arduinos.   And many use totally different processors.  The SDKs and Arduino boot loader quality for some are questionable.  You did not specify your Arduino HW.  And now-a-days, because of this problem, that is important.  But I see you are using an ATMega328P.  The same processor that is on a real Arduino Uno.  So if there is special hardware used to run the timer is should work.  I would next suggest trying one of the short example mills programs found at the official Arduino site.  Then work back to your program from there.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is just a logic error that doesn't immediately jump out: When the button state is changed, it will always set timeCheck equal to millis(). For instance, as long as you are pressing "P", stateP will not be equal to prevStateP and so "timeCheck=millis()" will executed everytime thru the loop, so the difference will never reach 500.

```
if(stateP != prevStateP || stateM != prevStateM){
    timeCheck=millis();
}
```

Should be something like:

```
if(stateP == prevStateP && stateM == prevStateM){
    timeCheck = millis();
}
```

This will continually keep timeCheck = millis() until either button is pressed. Once the button is pressed, timeCheck will remain at the value of millis() read just before the press, until the debounce value is reached (unless noise/bounce and not a real press, or button is released early as 500ms is a relatively long time).

This is probably the simplest modification to the code I can come up with. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a few things:

1) comment on your code -> lay out the basic logic so that you and others can help you debug it;

2) use brackets liberally -> don't rely on memory (=faulty) on the order of operations. instead, define it explicitly;

3) check your logic -> make sure that your code does what you want it to do;

4) pay attention to data type: 8-bit vs. 16-bit, etc.

5) modularize your code -> this allows more efficient debugging and code reusing.

for example, your code can be simply described as

```
  button_state = read_button(); //read button state, with debouncing
  if (button_state = BUTTON_UP) pwminc_dc(pwm_dc); //increase duty cycle, with boundary checking
  if (button_state = BUTTON_DOWN) pwmdec_dc(pwm_dc); //decrement duty cycle, with boundary checking
```

with the code modularized, you just need to worry about getting individual pieces right.